# Why does Vimium become unresponsive after yanking in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, vimium

In chrome, vimium becomes unresponsible after yanking, no keys seem to work.

What could be the reason?

I was expecting being able to resume work, tried esc, visual mode, searching etc. basically all the vimium commands.

Regards,

Comment: Fixed, in case someone had similar problem - Chrome restricted Vimium from accessing clipboard.